# Turn off safari "smart cut and paste"

Tags: safari, osx-lion

I'm trying to cut and paste text into a Google document while using Safari (on 10.7).  When I paste the text in, a new table is created surrounding the text.  This happens regardless of how the text is selected.  E.g. I can select one single character from the middle of a word, and safari will create a table when I paste it...  This is not an issue in Firefox, but I'm using safari for now until Firefox catches up with its 10.7 UI features.  Is there a way to turn off this behavior?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you pasting the text in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Paste And Match Style:

[image]

This will paste just the text you copied, without changing formatting.

Comment: what's the left-most character in the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Option. The others are shift and command. I normally use this; however, Google Docs sometimes causes problems with system keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Kevin: Official quick-ref: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 .  Also, the Input Menu (looks like a box with a command symbol it or a flag; assuming it's enabled in the System Prefs) has a **Show Keyboard Viewer** item that brings up a helpful palette with all these symbols displays on the appropriate keys, and shows the alternate characters you can type when holding _option_ or _shift_.